# How to list directories "above" working directory

Tags: command-line

My professor showed me how to list the directories above the current working directory using the cd command. I thought it was
cd ..[tab] 
but this lists commands in my current directory.

Comment: What you've already tried would work if you added a / (to get `cd ../[tab]`). @heemayl's answer gives arguably-better ways though.

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming you just want to list directories on the parent of the current directory, you can use `find`:

```
find .. -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name '..'
```

Alternately, you can use `ls`:

```
ls -p .. | grep '/$'
```

Or shell:

```
echo ../*/
```

or elaborately:

```
for i in ../*; do [ -d "$i" ] && echo "$i"; done
```

Or in `zsh` using glob qualifier `/` (redundant though :)):

```
echo ../*(/)
```

Comment: For the zsh, you could use `ls -d` instead of `echo` to get full `ls` semantics (like for example adding `-l`)  while still just listing the names rather than their contents.

Comment: @Darael Yeah but i intentionally wanted to just print the names, not the full stats..you could rather say that i might be better off using `print -l`

Comment: What I was getting at is that since the question is fundamentally about listing filesystem objects, using `ls` with the appropriate flag is the most usefully flexible way of getting the output. The ability to add `-l` was intended only as an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

`cd ..` navigates to directory above your current working directory in the tree.

For example,

```
home:$ pwd
/home

home:$ cd ..

:$ pwd
/
```

As for listing directories in the parent directory, heemayl's answer sufficiently covers that. I'll just throw in another one:

```
 stat ../* --format="%n %F"  | awk '/directory/'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list contents of "above" working directory (parent directory) use:

```
ls ..
```

However, it shows both files and directories of the parent folder.

Comment: The question says "How to list **directories** “above” working directory"